# How to custom sort a List<string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

Let's say I have a `List<string>` with the values of

- orange
- tomato
- apple
- apple
- orange
- banana
- banana

and I want to rearrange the values to the following order:

- tomato
- apple
- orange
- banana

The final sort order would be:
*tomato
*apple
*apple
*orange
*orange
*banana
*banana

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: show us what you have tried and what does not work for you

Comment: The final order you specify is a set because you have removed duplicates. Is that what you intend?

Comment: looks like it's not really sorting, rather finding unique values, in which case you can simply do `stringList.Distinct()`

Comment: I simply just don't know how to a custom sort. I know how to do structured sorts (alphanumerical, etc.) but I'm lost here

Comment: Sorry for the confusion the final sort order would be: 

tomato, apple, apple, orange, orange, banana, banana

Comment: SO is not a software writing service... this question will be closed in due course. You should to [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and show what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: This type of question is asked many times on SO. Unfortunately it is hard to see what you've already tried - so post is getting downvotes. Really unfortunate for the post to be authored by someone who did not want to demonstrate an effort. Anyway [this particular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3119659/477420) in duplicate should provide you with good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can order an IEnumerable including a `List<T>` any way you want. There are several approaches. A common one these days is to use Linq

```
List<string> newList = originalList.OrderBy(e => { your code here }).ToList();
```

You would replace

{ your code here }

with your own code to provide the desired ordering.

If you want to remove duplicates from the result, you can use

```
List<string> newList = originalList.Disinct().OrderBy(e => { your code here }).ToList();
```

If for some reason you wanted to order by the last character of the string, your OrderBy could look like the following (note: I don't account for the possibility of a string being null or String.Empty in order to keep the snippet short).

```
.OrderBy(e => e[e.Length-1])
```