# sort a list of strings based by comparing the datetime portion of the string

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I would like to sort a list of strings. the following example of pre-sorted strings:

> "2017-03-21 17:14:36.111 I like Red"
>   "2017-03-21 17:14:35.333 I like Yellow"
>   "2017-03-21 17:14:36.111 I like Green"

I would like to sort the list using the datetime substring only.

```
private void MergeAndSort(string[] lines1, string[] lines2)
{
    var entries = new List<string>();
    entries.AddRange(lines1);
    entries.AddRange(lines2);
    entries.Sort();
    foreach (string entry in entries)
    {
        CombinedrichTextBox.AppendText(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of this problem are you having trouble with? Separating out the date portion of the string, or sorting by custom criteria?

Comment: You could create a custom comparer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3119474/1454658

Comment: so why is 35 between 36 in the "pre-sorted strings" ?

Comment: the code you posted does not make sense

Comment: @ StriplingWarrior i have hundreds of lines from different files. each line starts with a timestamp as shown in the example.  i want to combine the lines (lines1 & lines2) into a single list then sort using the timestamp only.

Comment: @ Slai i'm trying to show that lines can have unsorted timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your date/time string length stays constant you can do this.

```
        string[] entries =
        {
            "2017-03-21 17:14:36.380 I like Red",
            "2017-03-21 17:14:35.380 I like Yellow",
            "2017-03-21 17:14:36.380 I like Green"
        };

        var data = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>();

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            data.Add(
                new Tuple<DateTime, string>(DateTime.Parse(entry.Substring(0, 23)), 
                entry.Substring(23)));
        }

        var sorted = data.OrderBy(e => e.Item1);
        entries = sorted.Select(e => $"{e.Item1} {e.Item2}").ToArray();
```

Comment: i updated the sample strings to show the need for keeping milliseconds.  is there a way to keep the string unchanged and only sort based on the first 23 characters in each string?

Comment: Why can't you stitch the string back together after sorting with the example i have given?.

Comment: Added the last line just now that shows how to concat.

Comment: thank you @Ahsan for the example code. to accomplish what i need, i changed entry.substring(23) to entry. this allowed me to have the full line unchanged in the second member of the tuple.  once again thank you!

Comment: Substring(23) returns the sub string STARTING at position 23.  To get the first 23 characters you need Substring(0,23)

Answer (score 0):

The cool thing about standard DateTime strings is that you don't need to convert them in order to sort them.  You can just sort the strings.

So then your problem is in figuring out where the date/time string is.  You can do as Ahsan suggests and use the position in the string.  You can look for the first letter in the string.  Which depends on what the actual strings and not just the examples look like.

Can I do this in just one C# statement?  You bet!

```
var sorted = lines1
  .concat(item2)
  .Sort((a,b) => string.Compare(a.Substring(0,23), b.Substring(0,23)))
  .ToList();
```

This example is a little sloppy because it assumes that there will always be a standard date at the front of each string, and that's often a dangerous assumption.  If you also assume that the DateTime strings are all unique, and the millisecond resolution would suggest that they are, then you don't need to do the Substring and you can just used Sort().

Comment: i updated the sample strings to show the need for keeping milliseconds.  is there a way to keep the string unchanged and only sort based on the first 23 characters in each string?

Comment: Of course.  My sample sorts by the date/time in the first 23 characters of the string as you can see from the call to Substring.